# How to enforce certain execution order for custom class-validator validate decorators

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

So here's the problem. Please, have a look at this DTO:

```
export class CancelFightEventDto implements Identifiable {
    @IsNumber()
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Min(1)
    @Validate(IsFightEventNotInStatus, [EFightEventStatus.ONGOING, EFightEventStatus.FINISHED])
    @Validate(FightEventBelongsToArena)
    id: number;

    @Validate(IsLocationProvider)
    @IsNumber()
    @Type(() => Number)
    userId: number;
}
```

The `id` property is decorated with two decorators and here is what they look like:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'FightEventBelongsToArena', async: false })
@Injectable()
export class FightEventBelongsToArena implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly usersRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    ) {}

    public async validate(id: number, args: FightEventBelongsToArenaValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        const [response]: [{[isFound: string]: string}] = (await this.usersRepository.query(
            `
                SELECT
                    COUNT(id) >= 1 AS "isFound"
                FROM
                    fight_events
                WHERE
                    "locationId" IN (
                        SELECT
                            "locationId"
                        FROM
                            users
                        WHERE
                            id = ${args.object.userId}
                    )
                    AND id = ${id};
            `
        ));
        
        if(!response.isFound) throw new ForbiddenException('Not allowed. Reason: Incorrect fight event id.');
        return response.isFound;
    }

};
```

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsFightEventNotInStatus', async: false })
@Injectable()
export class IsFightEventNotInStatus implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly usersRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
    ) {}

    public async validate(id: number, args: FightEventBelongsToArenaValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        const [response]: [{ [isFound: string]: string }] = (await this.usersRepository.query(
            `
                SELECT
                    COUNT(id) >= 1 AS "isFound"
                FROM
                    fight_events
                WHERE
                    status NOT IN (
                        ${args.constraints.map(status => `'${status}'`).join()}
                    )
                    AND id = ${id};

            `,
        ));
        if (!response.isFound) throw new ForbiddenException('Not allowed. Reason: impossible to cancel ongoing and finished fight events.');
        return response.isFound;
    }

};
```

The problem is that the execution order of these decorators is not guaranteed but I need it to be always the same.

Comment: I think you can seek help from this issue: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/399

Comment: @albert did you find a solution for this issue? it is my problem too.